# How to return bool while iterating list of nodes?

Tags: python

I have below code which does below things:

- Get list of all the nodes (ip_addresses) from `catalog_url`.
- Iterate nodes list and make `config_url` for each ip_address.
- Get json data for each ip_address and check whether json has particular things in it and basis on that print out stuff.

Below is my method which does that:

```
def verify( config_url, catalog_url, config, action ):
    flag = False
    response = requests.get(catalog_url)
    json_array = json.loads(response.content)
    for x in json_array:
        ip = x['IPAddress']
        # get data for each ip_address
        response = requests.get(config_url.format(ip))
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        # check data for each ip_address
        if(action == 'push' and data['latestCfg'] == config):
            print(ip + " downloaded successfully")
        elif(action == 'check' and data['procCfg'] == config):
            print(ip + " verified successfully")
```

**Problem Statement**

Now I need to return a boolean from my above method. If any one machine fails to download or verified successfully then I need to return false otherwise I will return true from my above method. I am confuse on how to do this in my above method with the setup I have currently?

Comment: can i safely assume that if `data['latestCfg'] != config` or `data['proctCfg'] != config`, it shoudl return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the flag to True before you enter the loop. If the download or check fails, you can set the Flag to False. In the end return the Flag.

The trick is to set the Flag to True before you enter into the loop. Then to flip the Flag to False when you encounter a failure. If you set the flag to False once, it will remain False for the rest of the loop even if all other items were successful. That way you know that you had one of them fail. If you want to break out of the loop and return, then do return False. That will break out of the loop and return False.

Here's how you can do.

```
def verify( config_url, catalog_url, config, action ):
    flag = True #set to True and flip to False inside the loop when if statement fails
    response = requests.get(catalog_url)
    json_array = json.loads(response.content)
    for x in json_array:
        ip = x['IPAddress']
        # get data for each ip_address
        response = requests.get(config_url.format(ip))
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        # check data for each ip_address
        if(action == 'push' and data['latestCfg'] == config):
            print(ip + " downloaded successfully")
        elif(action == 'check' and data['procCfg'] == config):
            print(ip + " verified successfully")
        else:
            flag = False #set to False if above two if statements fail
    return flag #if flag got set to False even once, it will return False, else it will return True
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `&` or booelan operator [`and`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), you can get `False` if any operand is `False`.

```
>>> True & True
True
>>> True & False
False

# or using `and`

>>> True and True
True
>>> True and False
False
```

- Begin with `True` flag.
- accumulate flag using `&=`

```
def verify(config_url, catalog_url, config, action):
    flag = True
    response = requests.get(catalog_url)
    json_array = response.json()
    for x in json_array:
        ...
        if action == 'push':
            flag &= data['latestCfg'] == config
        elif action == 'check':
            flag &= data['procCfg'] == config
        # If you want to stop as soon as operation fail
        # if not flag:
        #     break
    return flag
```

SIDE NOTE: You can replace `json.loads(response.content)` with [`response.json()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Comment: Aah. that's a neat trick. I wasn't aware of that. Also if I have more than one condition like this `if(action == 'push' and "isTest" in data and data['isTest'] and "latestCfg" in data and data['latestCfg'] == config):` then how can I use this `&=`?

Comment: `if action == 'push': flag &= "isTest" in data and data['isTest'] and "latestCfg" in data and data['latestCfg'] == config`

Comment: so basically just before that I can add it. make sense now. let me read more about this as well.

Comment: isn't it simple to just set the flag to False once when the failure happens. That is much easier than flipping the flag back and forth.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, You're right. :) BTW, once flipped to `False`, `flag` will not be back to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

maybe like this?

```py
def verify( config_url, catalog_url, config, action ):
    flag = True
    response = requests.get(catalog_url)
    json_array = json.loads(response.content)

    for x in json_array:
        ip = x['IPAddress']

        # get data for each ip_address
        response = requests.get(config_url.format(ip))
        data = json.loads(response.content)

        # check data for each ip_address
        if action == 'push':
            if data['latestCfg'] == config:
                print(ip + " downloaded successfully")
            else:
                flag = False
        elif action == 'check':
            if data['procCfg'] == config:
                print(ip + " verified successfully")
            else:
                flag = False
    return flag
```